# Google App Engine: Eclipse Plugin will not convert project with services to new gcloud sdk

Tags: java, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, gcloud

In the past I used this to convert my backends to services. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/modules/converting

Which left me with a project structure of

Container Project

- Main project
- Service 1
- Service 2

So I am trying to upgrade from the old App Engine Eclipse Plugin to the new Gcloud SDK and and I followed this page

https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/converting

But when I tell the container project to convert it says

> Failed to convert project "Container Project". One or more constraints
>   have not been satisfied. EAR 7.0 and Java 1.7 cannot both be selected.

I can run the server using the APP engine standard server configuration but when I go to a page, I get 500 errors in APP Engine. (IE class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap cannot access its superclass com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.AbstractSetMultimap"

Does anyone know what I need to do to upgrade to the new SDK while using services?

I used this tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe

UPDATE:

I found out that the new gcloud SDK does not support EAR projects and that you have to separate them. So I removed the EAR isms and added the 3 projects to eclipse.

However, we had it set up so that Service 1 and Service 2 would use the Main Project's code to do basic things like grab stuff from the data store and switch namespaces etc.

We would build a jar file for Main Project and attach it as a source to the other services. Now I get NoClassDefFoundError exceptions on both Main Project classes as well as classes belonging to the AppEngine API. For example.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/NamespaceManager
>       at com.dynactivesoftware.gaerdvark.core.GaerdvarkNamespaceManager.setNamespace(GaerdvarkNamespaceManager.java:202)

It seems strange that it would not find AppEngines NamespaceManager class. I checked the classpath and it does have attached the AppEngine API.

I assume that the way we were sharing code no longer works. How does one share code between services? Or is there something else I am missing?

Also I am baffled why AppEngine classes wouldn't be found.

Any advice would be appreciated. I am at a loss :(

Comment: My suggestion would be to not mix switching the SDK *and* converting the app in the same time. Conversion is a one-time deal and doesn't depend on the SDK - do it with the GAE SDK (or even manually) then deal with switching to the gcloud SDK. BTW - at least in python the 2 SDKs can coexist (on linux), I'm switching between them as needed - the GAE one is supported by PyCharm - I'm using it regularly, but some operations can only be done with the gcloud one.

Comment: The directions for migrating to the new eclipse plugin requires you to upgrade to the new gcloud SDK. That's the only reason why I did that. If I just update the app-engine SDK I assume I would still have to change the the gcloud sdk when upgrading the eclipse plugin. :(

Comment: I see. Sorry, I can't help.